# Does anyone have working Select2 + ajax in Symfony 4 without a bundle?

Tags: ajax, jquery-select2, symfony4

I am trying to make Select2 work in Symfony 4.3 without a bundle in order to keep it clean and small.

I have everything working except the ajax query.

```
$('#trabajo_equipo').select2({
        width: '100%',
            closeOnSelect: false,
            placeholder: 'Ingrese su búsqueda.',
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            ajax: {
                url: "{{ path('equipo_listado') }}",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,                
                data: function (query) {
                    return query;
                },
            },

        });
```

But I get this error instead of the expected list:

> App\Entity\Equipo object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation.

In the Controller:

```
/**
 * 
 * @Route("/equipolistado", name="equipo_listado")
 * 
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function equipoListado(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $busqueda = $request->query->get('term');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $equipoRepository = $em->getRepository(Equipo::class);

    $equipos = $equipoRepository->createQueryBuilder('q')
        ->where('q.marca LIKE :busqueda')
        ->setParameter('busqueda', '%' . $busqueda . '%')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    $responseArray = [results];
    foreach ($equipos as $equipo) {
        $responseArray[] = array(
            'id' => $equipo->getId(),
            'text' => $equipo->marca . " " . $equipo->modelo
        );
    }

    return new JsonResponse($responseArray);
}
```

And the request:
http://taller.test/equipo/equipolistado?q=Dell

Comment: You are hinting your object in the controller method instead of passing it as a literal and querying it yourself, and it doesn't exist. Post your method and request header.

Comment: Entry edited, thnx.

Comment: Looks like `term` is not being sent with the request. Try using `->query->get('q')` instead. Do you still see the `ParamConverter` error?

Comment: Yes, after correct that:
http://taller.test/equipo/equipolistado?term=dell&_type=query
Channel: request
Error: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "App\Entity\Equipo object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation." at C:\wamp64\www\taller\vendor\sensio\framework-extra-bundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter.php line 107

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this [course](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-forms/autocomplete-js) (text is for free) since chapter 23. They are implementing autocomplete.js, but all code is almost the same for Select2.